# Excel compare 2 columns and highlight when Exact Number of matches found

Tags: excel-formula

I have 2 columns with values. There are multiple same values in both columns but the NUMBER of multiple same values differs in columns A and B.

For example:

```
Col A: 25 20 10 10 10 96

Col B: 20 20 84 10 96 10
```

I.e. col A has 3x10 but col B has 2x10 AND col A has 1x20 but col B has 2x20

I would like to know if it is possible to highlight ONLY the exact number of multiple same values in both columns (in addition to duplicate unique values in both columns), i.e.

Col A to highlight: 20 10 10 96

Col B to highlight: 20 10 96 10

I am not very advanced with using formulas, I have tried 'basic' conditional formatting/highlight duplicates but I want to highlight the exact number of matching duplicates in both columns, not all duplicates.
I hope this makes sense! Sorry for not including pics but as a new user I am not able to ;-/

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need two rules in conditional formatting, One for `$A:$A` and one for `$B:$B`.

`$A:$A`:

```
=AND(COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,$A1)<=COUNTIF($B:$B,$A1),$A1<>"")
```

`$B:$B`:

```
=AND(COUNTIF($B$1:$B1,$B1)<=COUNTIF($A:$A,$B1),$B1<>"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Scott! I started to do it manually but it is an endless task - all done and easy now :-) Many thanks for your fast reply xx

Comment: @gala if this worked for you, please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Sorry - I am new here. Thank you for letting me know - I think I did...?